# Ubuntu 14.04 hangs at purple screen after it asks for my password

Tags: 14.04, system-installation, freeze

I have installed Ubuntu 14.04LTS onto a Toshiba Tecra M5. The install appears to have been successful but when it says "install complete restart your computer" the computer does not restart. It just sits there, then after a forced shut down Ubuntu appears to start, icons appear in the top right hand corner of the screen but after it asks for my password it just hangs up on the purple screen. Can anyone help ?

Comment: There is an open bug for Toshiba Tecra M5-388 failing with Ubuntu 14.04 ([launchpad bug #954500](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/954500))

Comment: It looks like a kernel bug. You could try booting into text mode, and then installing the latest mainline kernel, to see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be related to the Nouveau video drivers?... I removed mine and forced it to use the latest NVIDEA drivers (Vers 331. xx  - 32 bit...) It now boots up beyond the start-up screen and works fine, until you try to suspend the system.

Then the same symptoms occur as above (i.e. system freeze, but can switch to tty).  A full re-start resolves the start-up freeze, but the graphics s/w & firmware don't like to "suspend" with current combinations for some reason unknown.